# Comparing 2 dataframes to add rows if between dates

Tags: python, pandas, date, for-loop, python-holidays

completely new here, I tried looking up my problem but couldn't find anything quite similar!

I'm trying to set up a dataframe that contains the data for a schedule and its activity types. For example, if it's '1' it's a normal activity, and if it's '2' it's canceled, and compare that dataframe to another one to see if there is a date between the start/end date in the first dataframe, and if so, modify it so that it becomes 3 rows instead of 1, having the first Start/End date row until that said holiday, the holiday date row, and then the Start/End date continuing after the holiday.

I have no problem creating a single data frame, however my problem arises when I want to compare another series/data frame and potentially add rows that could be between said StartDate and EndDate.

Example
Schedule dataframe

| Start Date | End Date | Activity Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 2021-12-31 | 1 |

When compared to the other dataframe

| Holiday Start Date | Holiday End Date |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-02-14 | 2021-02-14 |
| 2021-07-04 | 2021-07-05 |

Ending up like this:

| Start Date | End Date | Activity Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 2021-02-13 | 1 |
| 2021-02-14 | 2021-02-14 | 2 |
| 2021-02-15 | 2021-07-03 | 1 |
| 2021-07-04 | 2021-07-04 | 2 |
| 2021-07-05 | 2021-12-31 | 1 |

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks, S.

Comment: What is the meaning of *Activity Type == 2*?
Your *Schedule dataframe* does not contain *Activity Type == 2*, so maybe it actuaally means "*Activity Type == 2* during a holiday"?

Comment: Activity type 2 would mean that's it's off for that day, so yes during a holiday it would be type 2.

Answer (score 0):

To present a more instructive example, I created *Schedule* as containing
**multiple** rows:

```
  Start Date   End Date  Activity Type
0 2021-01-01 2021-05-31             10
1 2021-06-01 2021-12-31             20
```

I created *Holidays* as:

```
  Holiday Start Date Holiday End Date
0         2021-02-14       2021-02-14
1         2021-03-10       2021-03-12
2         2021-07-04       2021-07-06
```

All date columns are of *datetime64* type.

A preparatory step is to create an *IntervalIndex* from *Holidays*:

```
ind = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(Holidays['Holiday Start Date'],
    Holidays['Holiday End Date'], closed='both')
```

To get the result from a single row, create the following function:

```
def getActivities(row):
    dd = pd.date_range(row['Start Date'], row['End Date'])
    ss = dd.to_series().apply(lambda dat: ind.contains(dat).any())
    s1 = ss[ss != ss.shift()]
    s2 = ss[ss != ss.shift(-1)]
    s1 = s1.astype(int) + row['Activity Type']
    rv = s1.astype(int).reset_index().rename(columns={'index': 'Start Date',
        0: 'Activity Type'})
    rv.insert(1, 'End Date', s2.index)
    return rv
```

To test this function you can call it on a single row, say, the initial row:

```
getActivities(Schedule.iloc[0])
```

To understand fully all details, save a single row of *Schedule* under
a variable:

```
row = Schedule.iloc[0]
```

Then execute each instruction from *getActivities* and see the intermediate results.

And to get the expected result for **all** rows, you have to concatenate
results of application of this function to each row:

```
pd.concat(Schedule.apply(getActivities, axis=1).values, ignore_index=True)
```

For my test data, the result is:

```
  Start Date   End Date  Activity Type
0 2021-01-01 2021-02-13             10
1 2021-02-14 2021-02-14             11
2 2021-02-15 2021-03-09             10
3 2021-03-10 2021-03-12             11
4 2021-03-13 2021-05-31             10
5 2021-06-01 2021-07-03             20
6 2021-07-04 2021-07-06             21
7 2021-07-07 2021-12-31             20
```

Fist 5 rows are from row *0* of *Schedule*, with 2 holiday periods.
Last 3 rows are from row *1*, with 1 holiday period.

Note that *Activity Type* is either the original value (for "normal" period)
or the original value + 1 (for a holiday period), so *Schedule* should not
contain consecutive values as *Activity Type*.